# How to eliminate space between page header and the top?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, header

I am starting to create website and I'm using bootstrap for designing. 
When I have this:

```
<pre class = "page-header" style="background-color:grey; margin:0px;padding:0x" >    

</pre>
```

I set both `margin:0px` and `padding:0px`. But when I open my file via browser, there is still a space between header and the top(below url palce).

Is there idea to fix it?

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but you have a typo `padding: 0x`. BTW, remove the `px`, just leave 0. And post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Comment: JSFiddle will help us and you both :-)